# Failed to export due to: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight, entity

Everytime I publish my code to another server, I get the following error
Failed to export due to: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

This is very frustrating, I have already checked and made sure all the project reference files are included.... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Stack trace?  Code that causes the error?  You have not provided anywhere near the amount of information needed for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue using AutoFac.  Basically I had this line of code and was getting the same error as you:

```
return builder.Build();
```

The exception tells you nothing as you know!  So you need to incorporate the "LoaderExceptions" as it says.  I came up with this that works really well and pointed me straight away to the DLL that was missing:

```
        try
        {
            return builder.Build();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
                var loaderExceptions = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
                throw new AggregateException(typeLoadException.Message, loaderExceptions);
            }
            throw;
        }
```

Now in the exception I get a bunch of useful information but most importantly the DLL I was missing: "(Inner Exception #0) System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"

I found that System.Web.MVC was referenced by a project that this project referenced.  So this project did not directly need it but one of it's dependencies did.

Put a try/catch like that around your code and I think you will save yourself a lot of pain.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain? I would have expected the build to fail before you attempted deployment. Did y'all never do a "Release" build in visual studio before deployment?

Comment: Hi @radarbob, I think in the end the underlying issue was that with MVC3, the DLL's were not getting copied to the test server, and they were not on there (I.e. MVC3 was not installed).  So release or debug this would work on the local box.  MVC4 fixes this now by being a NuGet package, so the DLL's are copied into the bin folder by default.

Anyhow, specifics aside, my answer just shows how you can get the ACTUAL issue highlighted, as it is not obvious from the default exception.  The actual issue could be different for everyone, mine happened to be MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

I use the nootn's try catch code around the Autofac Build() and got the following error,

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

This was because I was using MVC4 VS2012 template and by default the EntityFramework reference was pointing to EF 5 rc by default. So I `Uninstall-package EntityFramework` and then `Install-package EntityFramework` which install EF4.3. It's working now. Thank you nootn.